# (new Function(...)).toString() yields strange result

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

Try to run the following in Chrome and Firefox

`(new Function('a', 'return 1;')).toString()`

Chrome adds a `/**/` at the end of the parameter list unless there are no parameters. Is there any reason for that?

Both browsers seem to name the newly created function a name, namely "anonymous". Why does it name it? Surely, it doesn't give that name to all anonymous functions... If you just

`(function(a) { return 1; }).toString()`

then you get exactly `function(a) { return 1; }` which is what you expect. Furthermore, I can't call `anonymous` from inside the function - so it has a name but it's not included in the scope?

Comment: Afaik there's no spec on what exactly you get when you do toString on a function, so you might want to avoid doing it.

Comment: Do you have a specific use case or are you just curious?

Comment: @mplungjan At first I wanted to extract parameter names of a function but I hit the pesky `/**/`. Now I know what I should watch for, but I'm genuinely curious about what purpose could that empty comment have - maybe I can change its content or maybe it's part of some strange chrome optimisation scheme.

Comment: @thejh The spec guarantees that what you get is a valid FunctionDeclaration (notably, this *requires* a name) that "represents" the function. What it means to "represent" is a good question, however. (You often get things like `/* native code */` for built-ins; is it equally valid to give `/* user code */` for a JS function?)

Comment: On function decompilation: http://perfectionkills.com/state-of-function-decompilation-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is a comment in the [V8 source code](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/v8natives.js) relating to a "unbalanced block comment"

```
function NewFunctionString(arguments, function_token) {
  var n = arguments.length;
  var p = '';
  if (n > 1) {
    p = ToString(arguments[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
      p += ',' + ToString(arguments[i]);
    }
    // If the formal parameters string include ) - an illegal
    // character - it may make the combined function expression
    // compile. We avoid this problem by checking for this early on.
    if (%_CallFunction(p, ')', StringIndexOf) != -1) {
      throw MakeSyntaxError('paren_in_arg_string', []);
    }
    // If the formal parameters include an unbalanced block comment, the
    // function must be rejected. Since JavaScript does not allow nested
    // comments we can include a trailing block comment to catch this.
    p += '\n/' + '**/';
  }
  var body = (n > 0) ? ToString(arguments[n - 1]) : '';
  return '(' + function_token + '(' + p + ') {\n' + body + '\n})';
}
```